# Javascript Dynamic Button addEventListener not responding

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to dynamically create buttons within a div tag through javascript. The creation of the buttons themselves works fine and dandy but the EventListener does not seem to be responding when the button is clicked. Here's my code:

```
var container = document.getElementById("my-container-div-id");
var newButton = document.createElement("button");
newButton.type = "button";
newButton.innerText = "Button Text";

var handler = function() {
    myFunction(myParam);
};

newButton.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
container.appendChild(newButton);
```

The buttons come out fine but the asigned function will not be excecuted, even a simple alert() or console.log() gets no response when the button is clicked.

Comment: The scope of the handler is not window, but myFunction is defined on window, that's why it can't be found.

Comment: @Kokodoko This comment is not correct - anything defined on window will be visible inside the handler function.

Comment: The code works fine, provided that [the DOM is loaded at the point of execution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), `myFunction(myParam)` actually does something without throwing an error, and `document.getElementById("my-container-div-id")` exists. If you still have an issue, you need to [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], before we can help you.

Comment: @DuncanThacker good point, must've been tired :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you didn't have an element with the correct ID? Works fine for me:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("my-container-div-id");
var newButton = document.createElement("button");
newButton.type = "button";
newButton.innerText = "Button Text";

var handler = function() {
    alert("woot");
};

newButton.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
container.appendChild(newButton);
```

```html
<div id='my-container-div-id'></div>
```

Comment: Apparently the javascript was correct, the issue was on another part of my html code. The issue has been resolved. Thank you so much for your response, Duncan :)

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use **document.querySelector** for getting an dom element

please see below example for dynamic button creation with event handler.

```js
var divEl = document.querySelector('div.btn'),
    btnEl = document.createElement("button"),
    btnHandler = function() {
      alert('Hey you have clicked on me..!');
    };
    
btnEl.innerText="Click me to test...!";
btnEl.addEventListener("click", btnHandler, false);
divEl.appendChild(btnEl);
```

```html
<div class="btn"></div>
```